Logic App to copy outlook attachment to Azure Blob Storage
I am creating one logic app and integrating with outlook mail account and Azure blob storage.
When I am selecting blob name as dynamically Attachment Name then a nested looped is created automatically, for each 1 and for each (Before few months, there was only one for-each getting created).

After that when I am sending mail, during triggering I am getting below error:
InvalidTemplate
Unable to process template language expressions for action 'For_each_1' at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language expression 'triggerBody()['value']' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'Id, DateTimeReceived, HasAttachment, InternetMessageId, Subject, BodyPreview, Importance, ConversationId, IsRead, IsHtml, Body, From, To, Cc, Bcc, ReplyTo, Attachments'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.

There is a same question asked in Microsoft website but there is no reply from anyone:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1650651/issue-while-creating-logic-app?comment=question#newest-question-comment

Sorry but why are there two loops?

@Skin There is for each1 inside for each which is the nested loop (two loops)

I’m aware of that, hence why I asked … why are there two loops? What is the need?

I am not creating the loops manually. When I choose create blob and in the blob content option, choosing attachments, it is automatically generating the loops. Previously it used to create only one loop, now it is creating nested loop


Logic App to copy outlook attachment to Azure Blob Storage

I do agree with @Skin there is no need of two loops and To send Outlook Email Attachment to Blob, you can use below design:

Then( Get Attachment (v2) and Create blob actions):

Output:

Attachment sent to Storage Account:


I am not creating the loops manually. When I choose create blob and in the blob content option, choosing attachments, it is automatically generating the loops. Previously it used to create only one loop, now it is creating nested loop. But will try with above manner now once

I was previously not using Get Attachment, but instead directly having attachment name and attachment content in create blob. But now I used Get Attachment and now it is working fine. Thank You

Glad It worked now @Ram Grandhi

Thanks for your answer @RithwikBojja, I was wondering the same why & since when 2 loops get created when selecting attachment id. But this worked, thanks again.

Glad it worked out @ans2human
